# Azure DevOps - One Ticket visible on the default board along with a team board

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

If a ticket is assigned to a defined team board in Azure DevOps, is there any way to make it visible on the default team board as well?

So if I have a default team called Oversight and a team board for the analysis team and assign a ticket to them, I want this to appear in the default team board (oversight) as well.
I cannot see a way to do this.

Basically I want the team to manage their own board but for the PM and Scrum master to have oversight of all items assigned to the team and being worked on. It would be a bonus if the item progressed through the columns \ states it moved on the default team board as well.

Answer (score 0):

> > If a ticket is assigned to a defined team board in Azure DevOps, is there any way to make it visible on the default team board as well?

By reference to this doc: [Start using your Kanban board](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fboards%2Fkanban-quickstart%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%23add-a-kanban-board&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C4a0469969cd3412253fb08d8c26bf5f0%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637473116226247373%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=slh225%2FEM%2FsZ8UT7pu%2BfbvK5X71Kcst%2B9VtLnfsgCCo%3D&reserved=0), each Kanban board is associated with a team and a work item type. Thus currently it is not supported in Azure DevOps to view the same assigned work item in 2 different teams’ boards.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopercommunity2.visualstudio.com%2Freport%3Fentry%3Dsuggestion%26space%3D21&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C4a0469969cd3412253fb08d8c26bf5f0%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637473116226257367%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=CGvxXy66MypVv5XgwZtN72lOVS1oLQlFS8j2EDd6NN8%3D&reserved=0), which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Appreciate for providing valuable feedback to help improve the product.

BTW, you could add the default Oversight team to be member of the analysis team, and then member of this default team can switch to the analysis team board to view the work items. See: [Open your Kanban board from the web portal](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fboards%2Fkanban-basics%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%23open-your-kanban-board-from-the-web-portal&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C4a0469969cd3412253fb08d8c26bf5f0%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637473116226257367%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=lmBJ1XtcH5JAktLQe9%2FJn2yEy%2FV1xT8kB%2F987Wqg5to%3D&reserved=0) for more details.